# min, max and mean over large NumPy arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, max, average, min

I have a very large NumPy array: `a = np.array`. From this array I want to get the min, max and average which can be easily done with `np.min(a)`, `np.max(a)` and `np.mean(a)`.

However, I want also to have the min, max and average of a portion (begin part or end part) of this array. Are there some functions for this without creating a new array/list (because that would really result in a bad performance penalty)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

So, yes, just use slices.

Answer (score 4):

If the chunk you're working on is contiguous (i.e. no fancy indexing, in that case the part will get copied), you can use usual slicing syntax to get a view on the part of the array in question, without copying:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> part = arr[1:3] # no copies here
>>> part[:] = 22,33
>>> print arr
[ 1 22 33  4  5]
```